# How can I set other <li>'s opacity to 0.5 and keep the hovered one at 1 on hover in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Question is pretty self explanatory i guess. Here is the code I'm using:

```
function wkHover(){

    $('.worksItem').hover(function() {
            $('.worksItem').animate({ opacity: '0.5' }, 400, 'swing');
            $(this).css({ opacity : '1' });
            $(this).animate({ marginTop: '-10px' }, 400, 'swing');
        }, function(){
            $('.worksItem').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 400, 'swing');
            $(this).animate({ marginTop: '0' }, 400, 'swing');
        });
    }
```

It does everything, except setting the hovered ones opacity to 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is because `animate` has not finished by the time the next line is executed. I would use `not` to filter out `this` `li` so that it doesn't animate at all:

```
function wkHover(){

    $('.worksItem').hover(function() {
            $('.worksItem').not(this).animate({ opacity: '0.5' }, 400, 'swing');
            $(this).animate({ marginTop: '-10px' }, 400, 'swing');
        }, function(){
            $('.worksItem').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 400, 'swing');
            $(this).animate({ marginTop: '0' }, 400, 'swing');
        });
    }
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/fkaP6/

Comment: You're right. Btw: It should be possible to do the same thing with pure CSS, though without easing and would only work in modern browsers (see http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

Comment: thanks bro, worked like a charm. I'll accept this as an answer as soon as it lets me. Just a quick question though. http://www.egegorgulu.com/works/ this is where I'm using it. Any ideas on how to prevent the flashing effect when moving from one item to another?

Comment: @Ege Try moving over the area quickly for a few seconds. The effects will queue up. You have to clear them.

Comment: @Šime Vidas yeah just noticed it, ff seems fine but chrome was waay to choppy. I'm kinda of noobie on jquery, how can I clear them?

Comment: @Ege There are the methods `stop()` and `clearQueue()`. My guess is that you first stop the animation, and then clear the queue. But I haven't worked with animations much, so I'm not sure...

Comment: @Ege: check out jQuery's `stop` function

Comment: @Andrew thanks a lot guys, added a queue:false and it seems to have done the trick. Still getting the flash when moving between items though. Do you think delaying the hoverout animation would do the trick? if so, how can ı do it? =]

Comment: @Sime what did you think about the website btw? any feedback will be appreciated

Comment: @Ege: You could look at setting a small timeout before doing the animation using `setTimeout`

Comment: @Ege Your web-site looks great. `:)` I have no complaints.

Comment: Thanks @Sime. Really, thanks a lot for all the help guys, you ROCK! I think I'm done for the night, see you around :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Pure CSS:

```
.foo {
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 3em;
    -moz-transition: opacity, margin-top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity, margin-top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity, margin-top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity, margin-top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity, margin-top 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.foo:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 2.2em;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QxMfq/5/show/

The animation doesn't work in IE before version 10, though. However, the result in IE is still solid (just without the animation). The other thing is that (as you can see) you have to repeat the `transition` declaration several times for the different browsers. But this is only a small price to pay, since CSS animations are significantly more robust, perform better, and are easier to maintain.

Comment: Hey Sime, I would've wanted to do sth pure css with a jquery fallback but I think mine definitely requires jquery since other elements only get the opacity if one of them is hovered upon. Do you have any ideas on how to do it? I thought about a  ".container:hover .foo" selector but that would trigger the animation on the margins as well which is not that cool.

Comment: @Ege I'm not sure what you mean. A `.worksItem` element gets the opacity when hovered. I don't see what other elements are involved here. (BTW, the `#worksList` element and the individual `.works-meta` elements are lists and should therefore be represented with UL elements.)